# ajax supposed to add a session variable but not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've got very little experience with AJAX and I'm trying to get something that seemed simple enough to work.

I've got a drop down select form field calling a javascript function that contains an ajax call.

```
<select onchange="update_session_value('123',this.value)">
<option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>       
</select>
```

Javascript Function

```
<script>
    function update_session_value(id,value) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "untitled1.php",
            data: '{"id":"' + id + '","unit":"' + value + '"}',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
            },
            fail: function(data){
       alert('request failed'); }
        });

    }

</script>
```

Here is the code on untitled1.php that is supposed to be setting the session variable.

```
<?php
session_start();
if( (isset($_POST['id'])) && (isset($_POST['unit'])) ) {
    // save values from other page to session
    $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]['unit'] = $_POST['unit'];

}
?>
```

When printing out session `print_r($_SESSION)` , it hasnt been modified at all to reflect any changes being made by ajax. I don't think the ajax is working yet.  But I've reached my limitations in making this work.  And yes, I am using `session_start();` on both pages.

I'm thinking the issue my be in the data part of the ajax; however, I'm not sure...  `data: '{"id":"' + id + '","value":"' + value + '"}',`  I've looked up multiple methods of passing more than 1 parameter and I cant get any of them to work correctly.

Comment: Why does `$_POST['unit']` exist?

Comment: that was my fault...I deleted something when copying and put in value instead of unit....the data should be fixed now

Comment: In addition to `$_POST['unit']` not getting set, I don't believe that you can set `$_SESSION` as a result of an AJAX call, as, the AJAX is making the POST; you're not hitting the post yourself.

Comment: Correct the data parameter `data: {id: id, unit: value },`

Comment: @ObsidianAge sure you can...so long as session cookie is sent

Comment: @charlietfl - can you explain a little more on that statement?  I have still yet to get the session to set.  And I'm honestly not even sure if the ajax is processing anything.  I'm sure the success and fail are not correct...im not getting ANY kind of response...and when checking $_SESSION, nothing new is there.

Comment: I can get an alert on the variables inside the javascript function.,..but thats as far as i can get with results

Comment: Start by inspecting the actual request in browser dev tools network. See if what is being sent is what you expect, status, response etc. Is request being made to same domain(port, subdomain etc) as the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending a single string, you should send an object. That way you will have key-value pairs in `$_POST` and the values will be properly encoded.

Using your current javascript you would need to parse the raw input and decode the - possibly invalid - json.

So you need to change:

```
data: '{"id":"' + id + '","unit":"' + value + '"}',
```

to:

```
data: {"id": id, "unit": value},
```

Comment: so how would that be handled in the $_POST?  Would it still be automatically set to `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['unit']` ??

Comment: yeah i placed yours in and for some reason its still not setting.  Now, someone above mentioned that i cant actually set the session this way.  Is that true?  I don't see why It wouldnt work?  Plus, I don't need the session on the page live.  I need it for if the page gets refreshed.

Comment: @KDJ You can use a session like in any other php script, there is nothing special about an ajax request. You need to narrow down your problem, are the values in javascript what you expect them to be. And the same in php.

Comment: I’m able to pass the correct variables and alert them correctly in JavaScript.  As far as the php, I’m not sure how I can tell.  Is there an easy way to get a return from the Ajax? I know the session isn’t being set.  Not sure how to check the Ajax.  I’m trying to learn more about Ajax

Comment: I added `$_SESSION[‘hello’] = ‘hello’;` to untitled1 and that didn’t even set when I changed the select.  I don’t think it is connecting to the Ajax at all actually...hmm

Comment: I’m an idiot...haha...but no seriously...works perfectly.  I had moved the code out of my php rendered file into a basic file that was easier to work with.....and I forgot to add jquery.....your code works perfectly!  Thank you!

Comment: @KDJ If you want to see what your ajax php script does, you can output things there and check that output in the browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct the data parameter to

`data: {"id": id, "unit": value}`

And remove
`dataType: 'json'`